# custom option validation

Tags: custom-options, validation

I have a product with **custom option** using text field, I'd like a **validation** to it so that only letters is allow i.e. just like those "required field", alert message will pop up if your input it not accepted.

I have been looking around for hours to see where is the option-list located but with no luck.

Comment: I have not used this myself, but found this the other day. http://www.rocketweb.com/custom-option-validator - the code itself may give you some idea of where to look.

Comment: Thanks i tried the extension but it is not working for me, dunno why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally i found the custom-option-text field is located at:
..\app\design\frontend\base\default\template\catalog\product\view\options\type\text.phtml

for the line

```
<input type="text" onchange="opConfig.reloadPrice()" id=.... $_option->getIsRequire() ? 'required-entry'.....
```

I used "**required-entry validate-alpha**" to replace the default 'required-entry',
now for all custom options with text field it allows alphabet only, hard coded.
Hope this may help anyone in needed.

Comment: Don't forget to mark it as resolved. Also it can be useful to read this article: http://inchoo.net/magento/out-of-the-box-form-validation-in-magento/

Answer (score 0):

Magento does not natively support the ability to provide validation on [custom options](http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/difference-between-custom-variants-options-and-configurable-product-type). What you can do is take a look at the following third party module, developed by RocketWeb:

[Custom Option Validator](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/custom-option-validator.html)

I can't specifically vouch for it as I haven't found the need to use this before. But it is free and seems to do what you're looking for - so give it a shot and give us some feedback.

A great article worth reading which will allow you to implement it yourself:

[Mini Tutorial: Adding REGEX Validation to Custom Options](http://www.demacmedia.com/magento-commerce/magento-tutorials/mini-tutorial-adding-regex-validation-custom-options/)